# Conditional test inside command parameter

Tags: macros, conditionals, comparison

I want to call `\includegraphics` with parameter `width= #1\textwidth` if the number i have provided thru `\mycmd` is >= 1 and `scale= #1` otherwise.
I already saw this: [Can I conditionally scale an image with graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27083/92620) but i prefere to keep my code because it simpler, i dont want a repetitive code neither with `\ifthenelse` (repetition of the whole commande `\includegraphics`) i didnt succeed to use it inside the command parameter: `\includegraphics[\ifthenelse...]`, it better to only changing the parameter inside, so i need an extensible condition test inside the command parameter, also it would be nice if i can avoid the repetition in the OR in `\mytest`.

PS: i tried with `\ifnumequal` but it does only accept natural numbers so it doesnt help.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\mycmd{\@ifnextchar[{\@mycmdwith}{\@mycmdwithout}}
\def\@mycmdwith[#1](#2,#3,#4){
\ifnum#2>=1
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#3}
\caption[#1]{#4}
\end{figure}
\else
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=#2]{#3}
\caption[#1]{#4}
\end{figure}
\fi
}

\def\@mycmdwithout(#1,#2,#3){
\ifnum#1>=1
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}
\caption{#3}
\end{figure}
\else
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}
\caption{#3}
\end{figure}
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mycmd(1,example-image-A,test)
\mycmd[test](1,example-image-A,test)
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX won't expand your `\test` command in the `optional` argument and the macro is actually `\mytest`, not `\test`. It would be really nice if you would provide full documents, not fragments we have to extend to something useful

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i updated it.

Comment: It's still no LaTeX document

Comment: Well i think the example is now complete the errors are question related.

Comment: `\caption` is used outside of a floating environment.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti it is an illustrative example i know, do you want to remove or complete the code it will get bigger...

Comment: the point is you shouldn't post examples that generate errors (unless asking about the error) it just makes it harder for people to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry i didnt pay attention it was a compilation error i fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes very little sense requiring something like `width=1.2\textwidth`: if the first item is bigger than 1, the image would be scaled to be wider than the text width. And mixing `scale` and `width` is rather dubious.

However, the customer's always right. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{o >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}r()}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\mycmdInternalNoOpt#2}
    {\mycmdInternalOpt#2{#1}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdInternalNoOpt}{mmm}{%
  \mycmdInternalOpt{#1}{#2}{#3}{#3}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdInternalOpt}{mmmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 >= 1 }
   {
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}
   }
   {
    \includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}
   }
  \caption[#4]{#3}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering

\mycmd(1,example-image-a,test)

\mycmd[testopt](0.5,example-image-a,test)

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The list of figures (to show the optional argument is honored)

[image]

The page with the images

[image]

With just one appearance of `\includegraphics`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdInternalOpt}{mmmm}
 {
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \includegraphics
     [
      \fp_compare:nTF { #1 >= 1 } { width=#1\textwidth } { scale=#1 }
     ]{#2}
   }
  \caption[#4]{#3}
 }
```

Comment: yes i admit it makes littles since but it's very helpful to get used to latex this way, lol at the customer's always right, answer is clear and perfect thanks.

Comment: the question does ask to avoid repeating `\includegraphics` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Now you have to upvote

Comment: Andrew point out earlier that it will makes the solution complicated for nothing, a complicated solution with obscure code is never welcome lol i prefere code repete than an incomprehensible code

Comment: I would, but I'm not allowed to upvote my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

the requested syntax seems very odd, but width= and scale= are just variants of scaling with width implying scaling the natural width so you just need the following which avoids duplicating `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\zz[1]{#1\ifdim#1pt<1pt \Gin@nat@width\else\textwidth\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-4cm}
\enlargethispage{4cm}
\centering

X\dotfill X

\includegraphics[width=\zz{1.2}]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=\zz{1}]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=\zz{0.5}]{example-image}


\end{document}
```